# Uploading, modifying and download the same file in memory

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, apache-poi

I have to create an application that allows the user upload a specific Excel file. Sumarizing, the system needs to receive the file, write something in a specific cell and return the same file modificated to the view, then, the user can download this new file.

I'm using Apache POI for modify the excel file, but I don't know how to return this file to the view.

Upload view:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" th:action="@{/pessoa/lote}">
            <table>
                <tr><td>File to upload:</td><td><input type="file" name="file" /></td></tr>
                <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></td></tr>
            </table>
</form>
```

Controller: Here I don't know what I need to do, I call a method named "consultaLote" from a Service who is named "ConsultaPessoaService".

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/lote", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
        RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    try {
        cpService.consultaLote(file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message",
            "You successfully uploaded " + file.getOriginalFilename() + "!");

    return "redirect:/";
}
```

In the service, I can read and edit the file, then its generated a FileOutputStream. At this time I don't know how to continue, I need to return the file to the view using the controller, but I don't know how:

```
@Service
public class ConsultaPessoaService {

    public FileOutputStream consultaLote(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();

        File convFile = new File(file.getOriginalFilename());
        convFile.createNewFile(); 
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(convFile); 
        fos.write(file.getBytes());
        fos.close(); 

        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(convFile);

        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
        Sheet firstSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        Iterator<Row> iterator = firstSheet.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {

            Row nextRow = iterator.next();
            System.out.println(formatter.formatCellValue(nextRow.getCell(3)));

            nextRow.getCell(3).setCellValue("test");
        }

            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("arquivot.xlsx");
            workbook.write(outputStream);
            workbook.close();

            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            return outputStream;
    }
}
```

Comment: So you want to flush your file / make downloadable to user, isn't it?

Comment: yes, I need to make downloadable the file after modify it

Comment: Just to make sure that did your `workbook` object holds the new file after changing the values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return a byte array from `consultaLote` method. Method return type will be `byte[]` because you need this byte array to write the **httpservlet outputstream**.

```
public byte[] consultaLote(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
    //whatever changes you want, do it here. I am going to converting part
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    workbook.write(baos);
    // before returning you can close your your ByteArrayOutputStream
    //baos.close();
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

Now comes to your controller. We write the byte array to `OutputStream` from `HttpservletResponse`.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/lote", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
        RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,HttpServletResponse response) {
    byte[] fileBytes = null;
    String reportName="yourReportName";
    try {
        fileBytes = cpService.consultaLote(file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(fileBytes !=null){
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + reportName + ".xls");
        response.setContentType("application/xls");
        response.getOutputStream().write(fileBytes);
        response.getOutputStream().flush();
    }
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message",
            "You successfully uploaded " + file.getOriginalFilename() + "!");

    return "redirect:/";
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks man, its make more sense to me now, but I didn't understand the line:         response.getOutputStream().write(bArr);
what is this variable bArr ? its not declared

Comment: @MuriloGóesdeAlmeida, My mistake. It should be your declared byteArray and in the answer it is `fileBytes`. I already updated the answer. And again  if that helps then you should upvoted and accept the answer as well for fellow users of stackoverflow. :)

Comment: thank you! You help me a lot! I've done other modification, you need to put the if inside of the try, but is what I've wanted. Thank you!